# Execute a query using Hibernate-Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a query

```
select userid from userinfo where DATEDIFF(ExpiryDate,curdate())<100;
```

how can this query be executed using hibernate??

I have tried this

```
List<String> usernames = (List<String>)(getSession().createQuery("select userid from userinfo where DATEDIFF(ExpiryDate,CURRENT_DATE)<100;").list());
     for (Iterator iterator = usernames.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
      String username= (String) iterator.next();
      System.out.println(username);
     }
```

But this does'nt return any result is there any other way to do this??

Comment: change `DATEDIFF(ExpiryDate,CURRENT_DATE)` to `DATEDIFF(ExpiryDate,now())` and see if this works

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty:no, that isn't working

Comment: are u able to get the query and then try it directly on mysql..since if the query is getting sent as `select userid from userinfo where DATEDIFF(ExpiryDate,now()) < 100 ;` it should work.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: in mysql it is working fine, but here it is not returning any result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in the native SQL dialect of your database, then you have to use this:

```
List<String> usernames = (List<String>)(getSession().createSQLQuery("yourNativeSqlQuery").list());
```

Comment: first of all thanks as this does the job , but something native HQL would have been awesome. thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF` is MySQL specific keyword, not valid in HQL.

```
SELECT u.userid FROM userinfo u WHERE u.expiryDate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND :end_date
```

Try executing above query & set parameter `end_date` as (current_date+100).